# How do I use 'await' or '.then' to handle asynchronous export in node.js express with Logix.js?

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I'm tryin go share information between two Nodes, but not having any luck. I'm assuming it's because of the the methods is an async method, but the main mode won't let me use 'await' or '.then'

Node exporting the value (Logix.js)

```
"use-strict";

const PLC = require("node-logix").default;
PLC.defaultOptions.Micro800 = true;
const comm = new PLC("192.168.0.5");
var arr1 = [];

comm
  .connect()
  .catch(console.error);

comm.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("PLC connected successful! ");
  interval1 = setInterval(poolData, 1500);
});

comm.on("connect_error", e => {
  console.log("Fail to connect PLC!");
});

comm.on("disconnect", reason => {
  clearInterval(interval1);
  console.log("PLC disconnected reason:", reason);
});



function poolData() 
{
comm.read("SETTINGS", { count: 10 })
  .then(data => {
    arr1 = data.splice(0);
    exports.arr1 = arr1;
    //console.log(arr1);
  })}
```

Node trying to use it. (index.js)

```
/*Required External Modules*/

const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
var moduleL = require('./Logix.js');


/*App Variables*/

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || "8000";
arr1 = await moduleL.arr1;         // This is the issue 
console.log("hey: " + arr1);

/*App Configuration*/

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

/*Routes Definitions*/

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index", { title: "Home" });
  });
  
app.get("/user", (req, res) => {
    res.render("user", { title: "Profile", userProfile: arr1 });
});

/*Server Activation*/

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening to requests on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
```

Tried to use await and then. Neither will actually work. Expecting for the node to wait until there's actual value exported before setting it to the variable.

I've also tried:

```
    async function poolData() 
{
comm.read("SETTINGS", { count: 10 })
  .then(data => {
    arr1 = data.splice(0);
    console.log(arr1);
    return arr1;
    //arr1 = data.splice(0);
    //exports.arr1 = arr1;
   
  })}

module.exports = { poolData };
```

Along with:

```
moduleL.poolData().then((result) => arr1 = result);
```

Exporting just the tag itself (inside logix.js) does let index.js to wait for for the proper value to be retrieved. Using 'then' or 'await' gives an error since it's not a method.
But exporting the method (and returning a value) I get 'Unhandled Rejection ConnectionError,' even when I run the Logix node by itself it runs perfectly fine.

Anyone knows a way to export just the variable from logix.js but make index.js wait for it?

Thank you!

Comment: *"Neither will actually work."*: that is a vague problem description.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.